# How we can remove object from multilevel nested array and return parent array in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following nested array, I need to delete fields object with id 47 and return the whole parent array. How this can be done in JS?

```
[{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "phone",
    "fields": [
        {
            "id": 31,
            "name": "cellphone",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "id": 47,
                    "name": "android"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 32,
            "name": "landline"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 12,
    "name": "document"
},
{
    "id": 90,
    "name": "document-name",
    "fields": [
        {
            "id": 91,
            "name": "new-name"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I have tried following, but making mistake with the use of filter function.

```
private getUpdatedData(data, id, searchKey = 'fields') {
    data.forEach(function(ele) {
      if(ele.id === id && ele[searchKey]) {
         ele = ele[searchKey].filter(s => s.id === id);
      } else if(ele.id === id && !ele[searchKey]) {
         data = data.filter(s => s.id === id)
      } else if(ele[searchKey]){
         this.getUpdatedData(ele[searchKey], id, searchKey);
      }      
    }.bind(this));
    return data;    
  }
```

Comment: your expected output?

Comment: Its done with the help of following answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can made it by using recursive filter function.

```js
data = [{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "phone",
    "fields": [
        {
            "id": 31,
            "name": "cellphone",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "id": 47,
                    "name": "android"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 32,
            "name": "landline"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 12,
    "name": "document"
},
{
    "id": 90,
    "name": "document-name",
    "fields": [
        {
            "id": 91,
            "name": "new-name"
        }
    ]
}]

const filterId = (data, id) => {
  if(!Array.isArray(data))
    return data
    
  return data.filter(item => {
    if('fields' in item)
        item.fields = filterId(item.fields, id)
    return (item.id === undefined || item.id !== id)
  })
}
const filtredData = filterId(data, 47)
console.log(JSON.stringify(filtredData, null, 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `splice` instead of filter to remove the object from array.

```
private getUpdatedData(data, id, searchKey = 'fields') {
    data.forEach(function(ele) {
      if(ele.id === id && ele[searchKey]) {
         ele = ele[searchKey].filter(s => s.id === id);
      } else if(ele.id === id && !ele[searchKey]) {
        data.splice(0,1);
      } else if(ele[searchKey]){
         this.getUpdatedData(ele[searchKey], id, searchKey);
      }      
   }.bind(this));
   return data;    
};
```